# appengine_config.py Does not Load

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm using appengine_config.py to extend the pythonpath on google app engine project. The file though is not loaded neither on a request or when a new instance is started.

What are the possible reasons and how can I check what's going on there?

Comment: Is it at root level, the same level as your app.yaml?

Comment: Yes. Right after each other at the root of the project. Everything is running okay except that appengine_config.py doesn't load. I hacked it by importing it in the main file where it executes the code, but it's not the way and I'm not letting it in production.

Comment: How are you confirming that it is not being imported on startup ?

Comment: Put "raise Exception("app_config") in the file at one moment. It didn't trigger. Also, as I said in my previous comment, the code runs when imported in the main file of the application. Finally, in the version I'm testing on, I've moved a key module into the "lib" directory which I'm trying to add to the path. Is there better way to check what has been loaded and to monitor the early stages of loading?